# Shell script moving incoming files in to folder depending on prefix file name

Tags: shell

I am a total newbie and can’t pass a problem.

I have a process that transcode movie files to a folder. The files have a file name with two different prefixes.

I want to make all incoming `NT_*.mp4` to be moved to one other predefined folder and all `ET_*.mp4` to another predefined folder. They predefined with path and name.

Tried a simple `if $fname=NT_*.mp4` then mv file to `folder1` `elif $fname=ET_*.mp4` mv that file to `folder2`. And that doesn’t work, it just move all files in the folder to `folder1`, so that is obviously wrong way.

So what do I need to do for checking each file for it prefix and then move them based on the prefix to predefined folders?

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are important. It looks like you used something like

```
fname="wrong"
if [[ $fname=="right" ]]; then
  echo "Equal"
fi
```

You should add spaces around the equal sign:

```
fname="wrong"
if [[ $fname == "right" ]]; then
  echo "Equal"
fi
```

Comment: Well spaces doesn’t seem to be the problem, maybe I was a bit unclear.                                         File 1 ET_test.mp4. File 2 NT_test.mp4.                                if [[ $fname=="NT_*.mp4" ]]; then
  mv $fname $defined_path1                                 else mv $fname $defined_path2
fi                                                                                 Something like that, but working

Comment: I am sorry: I did not add spaces in my second example. Please compare the result of `fname=NT_something.mp4; if [[ $fname=="NT_*.mp4" ]]; then echo mv $fname defined_path1; else echo mv $fname defined_path2; fi` with the result of `fname=NT_something.mp4; if [[ $fname == "NT_*.mp4" ]]; then echo mv $fname defined_path1; else echo mv $fname defined_path2; fi`

Comment: Thanks, yes that and a a corrected misspelling in my script worked perfectly!!